# What to do if $(window).load(function(){}); is too early

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

I need to trigger a piece of code after every single bits are done downloading. The script works if injected after everything is loaded, but how do I trigger that automaticly?

My script is:

```
var divId = "jwplayer-0_wrapper";
if ($('#' + divId).length == 1) {
    myReg = /https?:\/\/www\.youtube\.com\/watch\?v=[^"]+/;
    var plainText = $('#' + divId).parent().children('script').text();
    var url = plainText.match(myReg);
    if (url !== null) {
        window.location = url;
    };
};
```

It is used to skip certain site that decide to use the JW player witch I find horribly buggy. So it looks for a div with the indication of the JW player and if there's one, it finds the link to the original youtube video and directly goes there.

Its triggered By Google Chrome Add-on named Javascript Injector and I apply the script on every  page I visit. The plug in work perfectly well on sites like [www.ayoye.co](http://www.ayoye.co/une-petit-singe-sachete-du-jus-de-raisin-dans-une-machine-jus/) and [www.veuxturire.com](http://www.veuxturire.com/chuck-norris-vous-souhaite-joyeuses-fetes/). But on other sites, that uses the same pathern, it seems that the script is triggerd too early. For example there [www.mondedestars.com](http://www.mondedestars.com/content/il-cree-un-spectacle-musical-avec-ses-decorations-de-noel/2013/12/21) and [www.lesautos.ca](http://www.lesautos.ca/voici-comment-les-russes-remorquent-des-camions/2013/12/6012) triggers it too early.

If I use the "inject now" fonction of the Add on after the page is really done loading, then it redirects me to the youtube page as expected. I am lost on the why it works some where and not were else.

I'm not trying to understand every single website here, I'd prefer make it dynamicly triggered after the page has done loading everything from its php, ajax, script, flash, html and CSS.

I've tryed to look to the JWplayer API, but since its terribly unclear to me, over the fact that its partialy in flash, it woudl be simpler if there was a way to trigger it after, or maybe just triggering it after i hover over the body, since every sites has a body. It cant be specific to one page.

Comment: jQuery document.ready() also doesn't work?

Comment: @DOK: `$(document).ready` fires **before** `$(window).load`.

Comment: Generally true, jQuery fires after the DOM is fully loaded and before all of the assets have been fully received. It's just something different -- and easy -- to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this

```
var timer;

function injectYouTube() {
  // DO YOUR STUFF HERE
  // ONCE DONE CALL clearInterval(timer);
  clearInterval(timer);
}

timer = setInterval(injectYouTube, 2000);
```

I am not saying this will be called after everything is loaded but instead you can make sure your code is executed when you want it to.

Comment: Thank yu so mutch, this was the last piece of the puzzle!

Answer (score 1):

The JWPlayer API are not that difficult. You can retrive the informations you need even not knowing the container id.
This is an example:

```
var player = jwplayer(0); // get the first jwplayer element of the page
var video = player.getPlaylistItem(); // get the player video  
var url = video.file // retrieve the video url
```

I think the setTimeout or setInterval are unreliable.
Setting up a listener on jwplayer `onReady` event would be better.

Comment: probably but I'm not that advanced in Javascript and it did worked out prety well, Thank you tough, I'll try it once I have the time to

Comment: I don't think setInterval is unreliable. Because in some cases you want to wait for AJAX calls to complete the DOM before reading it. So using setInterval one can keep tabs on target node.

Comment: what if the the AJAX call hangs for more than 2 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

The pessimistic answer to this is that you can't wait until a page has finished all AJAX operations etc. because web pages can continue loading new content indefinitely if they wish.

What you might consider is running your code every time a new HTML element is added to the page. This way, you can be certain to catch JWPlayer the moment it is inserted into the page.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", yourRemovalFunction);
```

Comment: Interesting. Is that supported in all majors browsers?

Comment: No (Firefox in particular has deprecated them) but they work in Chrome and so should work with your Javascript Injector add-on.